# How do I import from a MySQL database to Datastax DSE Hive using sqoop?

Tags: sqoop, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I've spent the afternoon trying to wrap my head around how I can leverage `dse sqoop` to import a table from MySQL to Hive/Shark. In my case, I am not really interested in importing the table into Cassandra per sé. Hive/Shark will do.

AFAIK, this should be possible given the `dse sqoop import help` gives me options to create a Hive table. Ive been trying to execute something very similar to http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpImport.html except I can't seem to be able to get the Cassandra username/password credentials to work.

Should this be possible? How? Do I have to go through a CQL table?

I am running DSE 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to do something similar to slide 47 in this deck:
http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/escape-from-hadoop

The strategy Russell uses there is to use the spark mysql driver, no need to deal with Sqoop. You do have to add the dependency to your spark classpath for it to work. No need to go through a CQL table.

Then you can join with c* data, write the data to c*, etc.